# how to make organization chart in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, charts

i have organization chart which is created in html page with use of css and jquery 
my html organigation chart is looking like this
[image]

till here i have not problem but i want to know that how the database value pass in this html organization chart for eg: i have parent name electronic in this have to child left side and right side how to emplement this in code this all name is staic in html in html is create just lick

```
<li><img src=“xx.jpg" width="86" height="60" class=“xxImg”> Father
       <ul>
         <li><img src=“xx.jpg" width="86" height="60" class=“xxImg”> child
            <ul>
                <li><img src=“xx.jpg" width="86" height="60" class="userImg”> hello 1</li>
                <li><img src=“xx.jpg" width="86" height="60" class="userImg"> hello 2</li>
                <li><img src=“xx.jpg" width="86" height="60" class="userImg"> hello 3</li>
            </ul>
```

with this help of my chart is run on webview so now i have to implement through  code please some help me how to start on this

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve, can you try to rephrase abit and give some more details?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will be probably not to store the parent's name but for each parent an ordered list to the children. You would have a structure like this:

```
"Electronics" -> { "Televisions", "Portable electronics" }
"Televisions" -> { "Tube", "LCD", "Plasma" }
etc.
```

If you have this structure you can make a simple [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (paying attention to enumerate the lists in order) to get the multi-level HTML list representation you want.